# Default Android Window Format

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a drawing app (Android 3.x+ target) that performs a full screen copy of a `Bitmap` to the `Canvas` in `onDraw()`, and I want to ensure I am copying from 32bit to 32bit, per [this article](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/). I want to ensure 32bit -> 32bit so that I have the best performance and so I don't have to supply any `Paint` to the `Canvas.drawBitmap()` operation.

When I create my Bitmap, I ensure that it is done via:

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Now, in my drawing Activity, I query the Window via [getWindow().getAttributes().format](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#format), but am returned OPAQUE (the default value) - question, is this 32bit? In Romain's article above, he mentions that in Android 2.3, windows are now 32bit by default, but a return value of OPAQUE is not so re-assuring.

If someone could clarify what I am seeing here it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a 32bit-bitmap, but you are not modifying the window-format. 
Add a [`getWindow().setAttributes(attr)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setAttributes%28android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams%29) to ensure a full 32bit-compatibility.